# A good way to implement an animated caret in HTML5?

Tags: css, angularjs, html, animation, caret

Some background: I am working on an application with an HTML5/AngularJS/Bootstrap3 presentation layer. The application is a musical score viewer and player.

The score itself is simply an image. I have successfully written code which detects musical elements on the page, including metric elements. Or, simply put, I know the coordinates of the bounding box of each beat, in each musical part. These bounding boxes are basically DIVs that are then superimposed over the score page image. So now, I can highlight a particular measure and beat as the music is playing.

However, what I'm trying to do is make it an animated caret. Just a vertical line which traverses each DIV in a known amount of time.

So, to boil down the question:

**You have a DIV. You want to draw a vertical line through the DIV that starts from the left, and ends at the right end, in n seconds.**

Any pointers by a CSS guru? Again, the environment is AngularJS with Bootstrap 3, HTML5.

Comment: I would not rely on CSS animations for this mainly because you can't pause, rewind, skip ahead, etc.  Use JavaScript to handle this - [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) is a great library for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position the caret absolutely and then use [CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property with "left". Make sure to use "linear" for timing function (see the docs for description of others, but for your use case you'd definitely want linear).

When you need to start running the caret, you could add a class to your caret div - and css rule for that element WITH that class would have a different value for "left", and the caret would move smoothly to the new position.

e.g.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#caret').toggleClass('endOfLine');
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
#caret {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  transition: left 5s linear;
  height: 40px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}
#caret.endOfLine {
  left: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <button>Run/Reset!</button>
  <div id='caret'>
  </div>
</div>
```